# Shares allocation based on minimum amount of tokens you have.

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, ratio

Given a total of x oranges, and y mangoes, how do you share the y mangoes among w number of farmers based on the number of oranges each farmer owns.

That is, If there are 5 oranges and 10 mangoes, then for every orange presented, the farmer gets 10/5 mangoes(2 mangoes).

The minimum number of oranges a farmer can have to have a share in the mango is z.

When a farmer comes to claim his/her share of the y mangoes, he/she must have at least z number of oranges. Else, his/her share is added to that of the other farmers.

That is, if the minimum is 4 oranges, and you have only 2, you get no mango and your loss(4 mangoes) is distributed to the other farmers that have the minimum number of oranges.

What simple and computational feasible formular can we use to easily compute each farmer's share as they present their oranges to claim mangoes?

Please sorry about the formatting. I'm new here. Thanks.

My incomplete/unsure solution:

Step 1: Multiply the number of farmers(w) by the minimum oranges required to get a share(z). Let's call the result MINS.

Step 2: Subtract the MINS from the total oranges(x). Let's call that REQ.

Step 3: When a farmer presents U oranges to claim mangoes. use f to compute the farmer's portion of the mangoes.

f = ((U - z) / REQ) * y

That's my solution so far. But it's not correct right?

Comment: If the number of farmers is unknown, this isn't possible to do precisely.  Where does this problem come from?  What kind of solution are you looking for?  Is there any more information you can give us?

Comment: The mangoes will be share based on the number of oranges each farmers has. The ratio of the shares will be x/y. It's just that there's a minimum oranges each farmer can have to claim a share.

Comment: Yes, you said that already.  When the first farmer shows up, he might be the only one, so he should get all the mangoes.  Or, there might be a million other farmers, and he should get one mango, at most.  There's no sensible way to do this without some other information.

Comment: The oranges are like ID. They are tokens to claim mangoes. If there are 5 oranges, then no matter how many the farmers are, the total oranges they have to claim the mangoes cannot be greater than 5

Comment: That is, the number of oranges(tokens) is known and limited.

Comment: "Proportionally" doesn't mean "equal to".  Please edit your question clarify it.  Clarifications don't belong in comments.  I'm still not sure I understand the question.

Comment: Isn't this like seat distribution after elections? Especially, if you don't want to cut mangoes in half. Your oranges are voters your mangoes are seats